# Weird 404 with angular uirouter and jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I have a weird problem with angular uirouter.

So the page loads but in the console I get 404 that users/login - templateUrl couldn't get load, but as I said before the whole page has been loaded (looks fine)

jade files:

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
    base(href='/')
  body(ng-app='app')
    .container(ui-view)
      block content
```

login.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 Log In
```

and this is my app.js with angular config

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/views/index'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/users/login',
            templateUrl: '/views/login'
        })

    }
]);
```

I think I should add that views folder is not in public folder (that's why I think I get this error) - but why then the page loads fine? (expect the 404 error).

Now I have seen, that when I delete from users/login.jade extends layout (line) then the page loads without 404 error, but layout.jade file is not loading anymore

//edit:

routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {

  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated,function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Members', username: req.user.username, id: req.user._id });
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/users/login');
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can we see your express routes?

Comment: thank you for your response :D! added :)

Comment: I think there is a chance that `req.isAuthenticated()` adds status code _404_ to the response before rendering it. So you might get _404_ status before rendering it. You could try to debug this by simple **testing** `function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.status(200).redirect('/users/login');
}`

Comment: nothing happens.. if I put extends layout line to login.jade then layout.jade is loaded, but I got 404 for users/login and login.jade is not loading anymore, but if I delete extends layout line then I got no 404 and login.jade loads, but then layout.jade doesnt :D damn...

Comment: I just look into the console! and I found solution! :D I have seen that after restarting the server users/login got 304, then CSS/JS files get also 304 but when it goes to ui-view it gets 404 because route for templateUrl is views/login not /users/login :D so I have to set route to specific site, not to specific jade file in views folder.. thank you so much! :)

//edit:
it works only for the first time.. if I refresh page then it doesnt load layout.jade again.. dammmn

Comment: I got to say something more :P after setting up templateUrl to "users/login" and adding "extends layout" to login.jade I get in the console "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once." layout.jade is loaded, I got no 404 error but again login.jade is not loaded. Whole HTML structure from layout jade is loaded and in view-ui layout.jade structure is loaded again - thats why I get that warning